# grep -v multiple strings from file

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have 2 files:

1. file1

string list:

```
ben
john
eric
```

1. file2

few rows:

```
 ben when to school
 my mother went out
 the dog is big
 john has FB
 eric is nice guy
```

expoted file :

```
my mother went out
the dog is big
```

I would like to use `grep -v` and remove the rows that contains the strings from list.

this is the idea but the wrong command :

```
grep -v `cat file2` file1 > out
```

Thanks

Asaf

Comment: This question is so confusing!

Answer (score 7):

Using a file for patterns:

```
grep -v -f "file2" file1 > out
```

or else you can do:

```
grep -v -e "string1" -e "string2" file1
```

Comment: Hi, 
not good :( 

grep: illegal option -- f Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . . grep: illegal option -- e Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: Run `grep --version` and tell me what you get?

Comment: grep: illegal option -- version
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

please let me know if its enough
file /usr/bin/grep
/usr/bin/grep:  ELF 32-bit LSB executable 80386 Version 1, dynamically linked, stripped

Comment: Which OS is this? `-e` is POSIX.

Comment: SunOS 5.10 Generic_147441-19 i86pc i386 i86pc

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, 4 matched lines should be removed one by one, and a single grep can't do it unless you define a REGEXP containing those 4 lines, which is tricky

But this script should do it

```
cp file2 out
cat file1 | while read STR ; do
    LINE="`grep \"$STR\" file2`"
    sed -i "/^$LINE\$/d" out
done

cat out
```